# Tabulator V5 Ajax Sorting

Tags: javascript, tabulator

I use the ajax sorting feature of Tabulator. This was working fine for me in version 4.9 but I'm struggling to get it to work after upgrading to v5.0.7.

In version 4.9 I just used to set `ajaxSorting` to true and provide the `ajaxRequestFunc` function call.

I've searched the docs and spotted that in v5 I need to set the `sortMode` to `remote` but there's no mention of doing anything else different.

The problem I have is that the function I've assigned to `ajaxRequestFunc` does not get called. When I click the column header, the table data gets cleared.

I'm sure there's something else I need to set or change for V5 but can't see what it is at the moment. Any help would be much appreciated.

Example working in v4.9 - https://codesandbox.io/s/ajaxsortv4-8lfkf

Example not working in v5 - https://codesandbox.io/s/ajaxsortv5-tw78p

The 4.9 example fires the alert when the `ajaxRequestFunc` is called. There is no alert in the v5 example.

Comment: Use `https://codesandbox.io/s/ajaxsortv5-forked-4izoz` this sandbox

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion but I need to control the server requests and paging myself. The ajaxRequestFunc call (http://tabulator.info/docs/5.0/data#ajax-promise) worked really well for me in v4.9.

Comment: see updated code.. I have updated code on above fork

Comment: Thanks for you help Double H. It lead me to realize that all I needed to do was to set the ajaxURL to anything other than blank then the ajaxRequestFunc gets called as before. I just set the ajaxURL to "dummy" because it's not used; it's controlled within my ajaxRequestFunc code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out all I needed to do was set the ajaxURL. I set it to "dummy" because it's not used in my implementation; I handle the ajax call myself within the code assigned to the ajaxRequestFunc.